# getting utf-8 error when importing snowflake data in power bi

Tags: utf-8, powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using the power bi snowflake connector to import data from various tables.
While it works for some tables, it fails for a particular table with special character.
This is the error I get.
Can you help?
Best[image]

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that you have Windows-1252 "Latin 1 Windows" encoded data, Microsoft's [embrace-and-extend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) version of iso-8859-1/ECMA-94.  Somehow the data presents itself to the Power BI connector as utf8 when it isn't.  When everything is correctly declared, the right software (ICU?) will correctly convert into Unicode and encode into utf8 before shipping the data to Snowflake.

You've got two choices:

1. Fix at the source (eg correct or declare correct encoding), or
2. Import as binary data and try to fix after arrival in Snowflake.

My best advise is 1. - to reencode it into utf8 before importing to Snowflake.

You can't put something into a text field that isn't a sequence of valid characters.  And in this case, you've got erroneous data that are not valid characters, so it is not possible to store as text.

How can this be?  It is all about encoding.  [An utf8 character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a chained byte sequence of up to 6 bytes that is decoded into a 1-5 significant byte Unicode character codepoint (skintone emojis are examples of long byte sequences).  The starting byte tells how long the utf8 sequence is, and the following bytes all contain two continuation bits 10*.  If the starting byte is invalid or the correct number of follow-up bytes don't have the continuation bits, you have an invalid utf8 encoding.

And how can this happen?  There are character encodings where every byte sequence is legal, like the 8-bit iso-8859-1 "ISO latin 1" or its extended cousin Windows-1252.  If you declare that this sequence of byte is utf8 and not iso-8859-1, you've suddenly got a sequence of bytes that may contain invalid utf8 (because it's really Windows-1252 encoding).

As of your error message, there is no legal utf8 character encoding *starting* with the byte HEX(92), which is a "follow-up" byte.